# Jupyter notebook table style changes when saved as html

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook version 5.2.2 with python

When I display a DataFrame in the notebook the table style looks really nice. Especially the alternating grey and white row colors. When I save the notebook as html the nice style disappears.

Is there any way to keep the style that appears in the notebook itself?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this. I have run into this problem before. When you convert the notebook to HTML you lose that styling.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is possible to change the CSS table settings. I just need to learn how to do that:-)